# ApacheDS service crashing after adding schema

Tags: ldap, windows-services, apacheds

I am running Apache Directory as a service on Windows 10.

I installed and ran the service and it ran without difficulties. Then, using the Apache Directory Studio (in Schema Mode), I created a new schema project, added a new schema with a single object type and a single attribute type, exported the new schema information to an LDIF file, and imported it back into the LDAP browser (as instructed in https://directory.apache.org/apacheds/basic-ug/2.3.1-adding-schema-elements.html).

As instructed, I then attempted to restart the ApacheDS service.

The ApacheDS service now will not start! When I attempt to start it now, it consistently shows the following failure message:

```
error 1067: the process terminated unexpectedly
```

Does anyone know what is broken in the server that causes this failure? How can I fix this problem and get the service to run again?

Answer (score 0):

The error could be anything, and might be as well unrelated to the schema update, to get more debug info, change FATAL in *conf* to DEBUG.
https://directory.apache.org/apacheds/advanced-ug/5.3-logs.html